# How To Install Ubuntu on an old machine without usb or cd

Tags: linux, ubuntu

How To Install Ubuntu on an old machine without usb or cd, I have an old Vaio laptop does not have access to USB and CD does not work, how I can install ubuntu on the machine?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about programming (or tools used for programming). You should probably ask on [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com/).

Comment: Pull out the hard drive put a ubuntu image on it and put it back in it.  Unless you are going tell us what peripheral you can connect to it.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Could it be "moved" instead?

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can first you need this tool

1. Refind
2. Ubuntu
3. extract refind in desktop than go to command prompt and select run as administrator
4. type " S: /S " enter
5. type " cd "C:\Program Files "
6. type " /E refind S:\EFI\refind\
7. type " cd S:\EFI\refind "
8. type " S: "
9. type " rename refind.conf-sample refind.conf "
10. type " bcedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\refind\refind_x64.efi "
11. done make sure the word is " The operation complete " with this now you have a boot menu that make you can choose the booting option
12. install free partition for your ubuntu os and also 8Gb FAT32 partition with name installer this is for you to put and your Ubuntu installer (you can delete it later )
13. extract ubuntu iso file to INSTALLER
14. after it done now you have to install ubuntu like usual
15. how to install ubuntu:
    just follow this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vaEYeQkTgzQ&t=219s on 5.03 for free space in windows and 7.57 to set up the partition in ubuntu installer as manual

skipped the setting boot priority because when you restart your computer you will find refind booter and choose the ubuntu installer.

i do this with using 2 different tutorial from agustian kamal : https://youtu.be/1ZmW-Y-pBQ0
and levelip Id : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vaEYeQkTgzQ&t=219s

note : if you cant add more than 4 partision you should change your system from mbr to got like this : https://youtu.be/nENTXwvHw3s
its allow you to add more than 4 particion

Answer (score -2):

Some tools on Windows (like WinISO or other) let you extract some files from the ISO image.

Ubuntu used to have a wubi.exe at his root from which you can setup Ubuntu from within Windows without needing to burn the ISO to a CD or to a USB and boot on it.

It is pretty convenient as it installs Ubuntu as if it was a normal software so you can "uninstall" Ubuntu at any time like if it was a regular software. It does so by installing a virtual partition on your Windows partition.

Ubuntu will work as normal, booting on its own virtual partition. And you will still be offered to pick which OS you want to boot on on startup.

It is limited to 30 Gb though, which is more than enough for the OS. I advise to keep your data files in a separate disk/partition anyway.

Comment: (Got a -1. Care to explain? I want to improvise if possible)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this doesn't answer the question.  OP wants to install Ubuntu, not run it in a VM on Windows.

Comment: @dimo414 The old Wubi installer installed linux natively on a windows parition. I don't think it's still maintained.

Comment: @dimo414 As Elliot Frisch precised it and as I poorly tried to explain it myself: You actually boot on Linux like if you did a proper installation on a separate partition, so it is strictly identical in that sense. It is **not a VM**.